# How exactly did analog TV cameras work?

Tags: camera, television

Before the invention of the CCD, how were analog video images captured? Specifically, what process occurred between the optics of the camera, and the resulting analog electrical signal (not necessarily ready to transmit)?

Comment: Welcome! You've asked some very broad questions. There are whole books on the subject. Two I'd recommend are the [Standard Handbook of Video & Television Engineering](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0070696276/) and [Video Engineering](https://www.amazon.com/Video-Engineering-McGraw-Hill-Audio-Hardcover/dp/0071350179/).

Answer (score 1):

They didn't need tape if they were transmitting live. They simply sent the signals to a radio transmitter, or to tape for recording.

This is how television and video worked for nearly 80 years before digital video came along.

I'd suggest reading the Wikipedeia pages on [Video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video) and the [History of Television](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_television) as a starter.

Comment: I just fail to understand which device exactly captured light and converted it to signal. I really can't think around the CMOS.

Comment: I think Michael's comment is correct then - you need to go through a much broader set of reading materials. I'll close this question as far too broad. If you read his and my links, that will start you off.